# SQL Server get number of days from date range excluding certain days from specific date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I have a table in database with records as shown below :

```
Id | Status   | UserId | StatusDate              | ProgramStartDate

1  | Active   |1       | 2014-04-02 00:00:00.000 | 2014-03-23
2  | Inactive |1       | 2014-04-05 00:00:00.000 | NULL
3  | Pause    |1       | 2014-04-07 00:00:00.000 | NULL
4  | Inactive |1       | 2014-04-10 00:00:00.000 | NULL
5  | Active   |1       | 2014-04-14 00:00:00.000 | NULL
```

`ProgramStartDate` is any date that is inserted by user. While `StatusDate` is actual date-time whenever user have inserted/updated his Status.

Now, I want to **count** the **number of days** from `ProgramStartDate (2014-03-23) to Today's date (GETDATE())` excluding the number of days in which user was in ***Inactive*** status.

Here, user is ***Active*** from `ProgramStartDate` `2014-03-23 to 2014-04-05` (**13** Days), `2014-04-07 to 2014-04-10` (**3** days), and `2014-04-14 to GETDATE()` (**9** days)
So **total number of active days** = 13 + 3 + 9 **=**  **25 days**.

The formula work is like below example :

```
'2014/03/23'    '2014/04/05'    13
'2014/04/05'    '2014/04/07'    -2
'2014/04/07'    '2014/04/10'    3
'2014/04/10'    '2014/04/14'    -4
'2014/04/14'    GetDate()   9
```

and total = 25 days.

Is there any way to achieve this Total Number of Days by SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution for your query. try it now.

```
Select SUM(TDays) SumDays
From (
Select Id, Status, UserId, 
    Case When (Status = 'Inactive') Then 0 Else
        (DATEDIFF(DAY,StatusDate,(Case When (NextDate IS NULL) Then GetDate() Else NextDate End)))
    End TDays
From (
    Select Id, Status, UserId, Case When (ProgramStartDate IS NOT NULL) Then ProgramStartDate Else StatusDate End StatusDate,
        (Select Min(StatusDate) From StatusMast M Where M.StatusDate > S.StatusDate) NextDate
    From StatusMast S
) As Stat
)As TotDay
```

Your output is :

```
SumDays
25
```

Comment: if anything else let me know